# Duplicate entry being creating in array of objects when pushing the same data in two different arrays

Tags: angular

I am having a weird problem all because of  `allIpRecords: any;` in which I want to maintain a copy of the `ipRecords: any;` because in the original code the `ipRecords` may change and I want to retain the previous copy in `allIpRecords`
The problem is whenever the insert function runs and if I have `this.allIpRecords = res.data;` inside the insert function then in both the arrays `ipRecords` and `this.allIpRecords` duplicate entries of the inserted row gets created and in the table the same row is shown two times. If I remove the `this.allIpRecords` then nothing of this sort happens only single entry of the inserted items is there in the array. 
Even though in the database it is only inserted once but in the local array its shown two times.

```
   <td>
              <span></span>
          </td>
          <td>
              <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="newData.ip" />
          </td>
          <td>
              <input type="text"  [(ngModel)]="newData.forDomain" />
          </td>
          <td>
              <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="newData.status" />
          </td>
          <td>
              <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="newData.senderEmail" />
          </td>
          <td>
              <button class="common-btn" type="button" (click)="insert()">Insert</button>
          </td>


           </tr>
      <tr *ngFor="let record of ipRecords" class="colour02">
      <td>{{record.id}}</td>
      <td *ngIf="record.id === editRowId"><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="record.ip" ></td>
      <td *ngIf="record.id !== editRowId">{{record.ip}}</td>
      <td *ngIf="record.id === editRowId"><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="record.forDomain" ></td>
      <td *ngIf="record.id !== editRowId">{{record.forDomain}}</td>
      <td *ngIf="record.id === editRowId"><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="record.status" ></td>
      <td *ngIf="record.id !== editRowId">{{record.status}}</td>
      <td *ngIf="record.id === editRowId"><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="record.senderEmail" ></td>
      <td *ngIf="record.id !== editRowId">{{record.senderEmail}}</td>
      <td>
      <br>
```

Ts

```
       private newData: any = {};
       ipRecords: any;
       allIpRecords: any;

        ngOnInit() {
        this.auth.getAllIpRecords().subscribe((res: any)=>{
       this.ipRecords = res.data;
       this.allIpRecords = res.data;
       }
        }


        insert() {
if(Object.keys(this.newData).length === 0) {
  this.toastr.error("Empty record");
  return;
}
this.auth.addIpRecord(this.newData).subscribe((res: any)=>{
  if(res.status === "Success") {
    this.newData = {};
    this.ipRecords.push(res.data);
    this.allIpRecords.push(res.data);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On both variables, you are passing the same object reference -

```
this.ipRecords = res.data;
this.allIpRecords = res.data;
```

So, modification on any one variable will change all of them because they are the same reference.

To solve this, clone **res.data** and then assign it to the variables. There is an easy trick to do this by using *JSON.stringify()* and *JSON.parse()*

```
this.ipRecords = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res.data));
this.allIpRecords = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res.data));
```

You can find more detailed information about object cloning [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object)

Comment: That works but cant really fathom both are totally different arrays still one effects the other just because they have the same data

Comment: They hold reference to the same data. Kind of like the pointers. So, actually it's just one data but you can access it through two reference.

Comment: Imagine you have a house work two does where you store boxes. You can add or remove boxes through one door, and when you enter through the other you will see the changes in the boxes.